# How to Generate and Print An Array with Random Numbers in Python in the Bingo Way with No Duplication

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Django. I am trying to solve a Bingo card game problem, where I have to generate an array and print the random numbers without any duplication.

I have to print this output:

```
     W      O      R      L      D 
W   10     93     85     14     18    
O   24     96     88     29     23    
R   36     33     99     90     31     
L   46     48     92     95     43     
D   59     76     51     72     58
```

It's a bingo game. The card gets filled with random Numbers. I have tried the following codes:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = random.sample(range(1,100),5)
        self.i = random.sample(range(1,100),5)
        self.n = random.sample(range(1,100),5)
        self.g = random.sample(range(1,100),5)
        self.o = random.sample(range(1,100),5)

        print(self.b)
        print(self.i)
        print(self.n)
        print(self.g)
        print(self.o)
```

The codes don't deliver the desired output.

Comment: Why do you always sample from the range `1..100` while it must be `10..20` for the first row, `20..30` for the second etc?

Comment: (1) Your desired output shows a 6x6 array; your code does 5x5; (2) your sample ranges don't match the desired output; (3) you've done nothing to avoid duplication.  SO handles one problem per posting; this posting suggests that you need to work on several aspects of your class materials before your ready to post.

Comment: In the meantime, also look at `random.sample` to avoid duplication.

Comment: @Prune I have updated the question.

Comment: @Seluck As mentioned in the question, they are random numbers.

Comment: If I am not wrong, This is not exactly a 5D array, its a 2D array with 5 rows. you might want to correct the question to find relevant answers.

Comment: @Prune As mentioned in the question, they are random numbers.

Comment: @Prune no. It's a five dimensional array. Five rows and five columns. I am updating this question to make it look easier for you.

Comment: 5x5 is a 2D array, not 5D.  I'll be happy to help once you've addressed the outstanding issues.

Comment: @Prune I have updated the question. It should be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
from random import randint

class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data1d = []
        for i in range(25):
            self.data1d.append(randint(1, 100))

        duplicate = True
        while duplicate == True:
            duplicate = False
            for j in range(len(self.data1d)):
                for i in range(len(self.data1d)):
                    if i != j and self.data1d[i] == self.data1d[j]:
                        self.data1d[j] = randint(1, 100)
                        duplicate = True

        self.data = []

        for j in range(5):
            row = []
            for i in range(5):
                row.append(self.data1d[j * 5 + i])

            self.data.append(row)

        letters = ['W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']
        printText = ['      ', '']
        for i in letters:
            printText[0] += i + '     '

        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            text = letters[j] + '   '
            for i in self.data[j]:
                if i < 10:
                    space = '  '
                elif i < 100:
                    space = ' '
                else:
                    space = ''
                text += space + str(i) + '   '

            printText.append(text)

        for i in printText:
            print(i)

c = Card()
```

Comment: It's almost done. However, it is producing duplicate numbers. I need to generate unique random numbers and avoid duplication.

Comment: I'll try to add that feature.

Comment: The range of random numbers is 0 - 100.

Comment: Do you want 100 and 0 to be included?

Comment: In your wanted output example, the numbers from 0 to 9 are not used. Do you want me to include 0 to 9?

Comment: Yes, 100 needs to be included, as the range is 1 - 100. In my previous message, I said 0 - 100. That was a mistake. The range is 1 - 100.

Comment: Yes. Please, include 0 to 9.

Comment: Sorry, but some clarification would help. Do you want the range to be 0 to 100 inclusive or 1 to 100 inclusive?

Comment: The range to needs be 1 to 100 inclusive.

Comment: I have chosen your answer as the correct one. However, there are some codes that I need to be clear about. I will inform about them soon.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the lines 9 - 20. I am not clear about eliminating the duplicates. Would you please explain these lines?

Comment: The while loop is going to always repeat until it "realises" that duplicate equals false. It can only "realise" that duplicate equals true or false at the start of each new iteration.

Comment: The first for loop (with j as the index) goes through the index of each of the numbers previously generated for the grid. The for loop nested inside the other for loop will also go through the index of each of the numbers generated but will check that i (the index of the number it is checking is or is not duplicated somewhere else) and j (the number it is checking against the other number for duplication) are not equal.

Comment: If they WERE equal, that would mean it is checking for duplication against itself so we skip over that. If it is NOT checking against itself, then we check if the number in the grid at the position j (the index of the one we're searching for to check if occurring multiple times) and position i (the one we're currently checking against the value at position j) are equal. If they ARE equal, we chose a new value for them and set duplicate to true. This ensures that we repeat again just in case the value we chose doesn't occur any more than once in the grid.